# Autocomplete commands with argcomplete and Poetry

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse, python-poetry

I'm currently trying Poetry to manage my dependencies, for a project using `argparse` and `argcomplete`. However, I can't figure out how to handle autocompletion with the `run` command of Poetry. I have a command `mycommand` which I can run with `poetry run mycommand`, but the autocompletion does not works. But it works when I create a virtual environnement with `venv` and do `python main.py` (which runs `mycommand`). In both cases I did `activate-global-python-argcomplete` before.

So is there any way to make the autocompletion work with Poetry? Also, will it still work if I compile the Python source to an executable (e.g. with `pyinstaller`)?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue while trying to use argcomplete for the first time, but I found a way to make it work.

I assume that like me, you followed the README and used the script `activate-global-python-argcomplete`. This script will enable autocompletion on any script that contains `PYTHON_ARGCOMPLETE_OK` in the fist 1024 characters of the file. However, when you run it with poetry (or from an packaged executable), the script being scanned will not be yours but poetry's executable file (or a small file wrapper in the executable case).

### Solution 1

However, you can make it work by registering your command specifically using `register-python-argcomplete` like this:

```
register-python-argcomplete my-awesome-command > ~/.bash_completion.d/my-awesome-command
```

(replace `my-awesome-command` with the name of your own awesome command)

And then add this to your `.bashrc`

```
source ~/.bash_completion.d/my-awesome-command
```

This worked for me.

### Solution 2

I also found a kind of hack that worked to make the executable packaged by poetry compatible with argcomplete's global completion activation:

For this, I renamed my `main` method to `main_PYTHON_ARGCOMPLETE_OK`, and I updated my pyproject.toml.

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
  # BEFORE
  # my-awesome-command = 'my.awesome.lib:main'
  # AFTER
  my-awesome-command = 'my.awesome.lib:main_PYTHON_ARGCOMPLETE_OK'
```

This made sure that the wrapper script generated by poetry contained the string `PYTHON_ARGCOMPLETE_OK`, which did the trick ;-)